# How do I connect two arcs with a line in this d3.js visual

Tags: svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I saw an infographic online that I wanted to use as a challenge to learn d3.js.  The original infographic is here:

http://www.shah3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/IG-WWF-Dehahs.png

I've made a start here:
http://www.tips-for-excel.com/d3test/arc/arc%20test.html

You'll notice that the original has nice lines that link an arc from the bottom with an arc along the top.  So far I can only think of painfully placing lots of circles to achieve this effect, hence the odd red circle currently in my visual.  What would people's best methods be to replicate the original graphic?  Which element would make this task easier?  Arcs? Lines?  I imagine I'll have to manipulate my data so that the lines go where they're meant to.

Happy to give more info if needed and thanks for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few existing diagrams to work off of from d3's [galleries](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery):

http://bl.ocks.org/4062006

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/

Both use the length of the chord as the width of the stroke (initially), but you can tinker with that, for sure.

Graphically, you could use [arcs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands), or full circles with a clip around it. As to the 'best' way to do it, that may come out of 'requirements' of how your graphic needs to behave (animation, relative arc placement, etc).

Personally, I'd go with path arcs.